# Posso comercializar um software que utiliza uma licença GPL?

Tags: licença

> Antes de mais nada, devo dizer que não estou fazendo uso de um Software sob a licença GPL, e sim de um pacote onde o código fonte original não foi alterado, e utilizo apenas a DLL gerada.

Digamos que eu tenha em meu sistema um pacote sob a [licença GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html), como o [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data). Eu utilizo este pacote para realizar conexão ao banco de dados MySQl.

Utilizando somente este pacote em meu projeto, eu sou obrigado a disponibilizar o código fonte do meu projeto todo caso resolva comercializar?

Comment: Como já tinha resposta, eu segurei o voto de fechamento. Como o @Rodorgas resumiu bem o assunto, vou votar pra fechar, pois entendo que a pergunta (apesar de interesse de programador) não pode ser respondida por uma comunidade de programadores, tampouco é um problema da programação em si.

Answer (score 11):

Se você distribuir seu aplicativo e tiver usado alguma coisa GPL como parte do seu aplicativo (mesmo que seja apenas uma biblioteca), e mesmo se você não cobrar dinheiro, você deve tornar o código fonte do seu aplicativo disponível. Já se for um aplicativo de uso interno ou se for usado no server-side de um website, não é necessário liberar o seu código fonte.

A GPL é como um vírus: infecta tudo que toca, forçando-os a serem também open source :)

Muitos sistemas de código-fechado oferecem uma maneira para que o próprio usuário baixe os componentes GPL de forma separada. É a única maneira legal de escapar das obrigações das licenças.

A [própria GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) menciona que talvez seja mais útil licenciar bibliotecas de sub-rotina com a LGPL, que permite a associação com programas de código fechado.

> This General Public License does not permit incorporating your program into proprietary programs. If your program is a subroutine library, you may consider it more useful to permit linking proprietary applications with the library. If this is what you want to do, use the GNU Lesser General Public License instead of this License.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode vender softwares, pacotes ou qualquer outro elemento baseado em uma licença GNU/GPL. Muita gente acredita que o espirito do projeto GNU está em não cobrar pela distribuição de cópias do produto final, porém, isso não tem nada haver com essa licença.

Porém, para comercializar este software você deverá manter o pacote que está sobre a licença GPL sempre aberto, ou seja, precisa disponibilizar o acesso ao código fonte deste pacote de forma aberta, não poderá fechar essa parte do software.

Quando falo em fechar, estou me referindo ao fato de que, você não poderá impedir ou dificultar que terceiros tenham acesso a está parte do software, que é justamente o pacote baseado em GPL.

Para maiores informações acesse: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.pt-br.html

No site em questão tem um trecho que diz muito, segue:

> A palavra “free” tem dois significados válidos em inglês: pode ser
>   referente tanto à liberdade quanto ao preço. Quando falamos de
>   software livre (“free software”, em inglês), estamos nos referindo à
>   liberdade e não ao preço. (Pense em “liberdade de expressão” (“free
>   speech”), não em “cerveja grátis” (“free beer”).) Precisamente, isso
>   significa que um usuário é livre para executar, alterar e redistribuir
>   o programa, com ou sem alterações.